# Vanishing homology of simplicial complexes with few facets

Tags: co.combinatorics, simplicial-complexes

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex with $n$ vertices and $n-t$ facets, where $t \geq 3$.

Is it true that the $(n-3-j)$th reduced homology (with coefficients in a field) of $K$ vanishes for $0 \leq j \leq t-2\,$?

Comment: Don't you have a 0-dim facet for each vertex (for a total of n)? What is the definition of facet?

Comment: "Facets" are maximal faces.

Comment: Thank you. (Sometimes facets may mean the next to the last dimension).

Comment: Just in case (sorry): does *maximal* mean of *maximal dimension* or *with respect to inclusion* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the nerve lemma, your complex is homotopy equivalent to a complex with $n-t$ vertices and therefore has trivial homology in degrees greater than $n-t-2$